# How to increment QLCDNumber in python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4, qlcdnumber

I am trying to update the value of a QLCDNumber. What I want to be able to do is run a function in a separate thread that outputs a value (in this case just counting upwards) and have this value displayed to the screen.

Here is the python script that I am using, and below that is the contents of the .ui file (where the QLCDNumber is named "disp"):

```
import sys
import threading
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import uic
from time import sleep


Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("./disp.ui")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    counter = pyqtSignal(int)
    counting = False

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.disp.display(?????) #<---- 


    def startCounting(self):
        if not self.counting:
            self.counting = True
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.something)
            thread.start()

    def something(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.counter.emit(int(i))
            sleep(0.5)
        self.counting = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

.ui file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>577</width>
    <height>504</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QLCDNumber" name="disp"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>577</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you are emitting a signal with the new value however your signal is not connected to any function, you just need to create a function to update value of QLCDNumber and connect your signal counter to this function :

```
import sys
import threading

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import uic

from time import sleep


Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("./disp.ui")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    counter = pyqtSignal(int)
    counting = False

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.counter.connect(self.update_lcd)
        # self.startCounting()

    def update_lcd(self, value):
        self.disp.display(value)

    def startCounting(self):
        if not self.counting:
            self.counting = True
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.something)
            thread.start()

    def something(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.counter.emit(int(i))
            sleep(0.5)
        self.counting = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would suggest to use [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) or [QRunnable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html) instead of threading module to start your background task. A nice explanation of the difference can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791824/c-qt-qthread-vs-qrunnable).

Comment: I tried adding in this extra function like you suggested but it still doesn't work. Is there another step that is needed, at the moment the counter just sits at zero (on the plus it loads properly now)?

Comment: do you have a button or anything that triggers `startCounting` function ?
If not you need to run this function in `__init__` to see something. I have added a commented code in the answer's code that you can uncomment to see the actual behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your help