# How to improve my program with Multi-threading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5, worker, qrunnable

I wrote a longer code, to read out the weight of tem balances and print them in an excel file. Now I want to add a "plot" function which, plot the ten last values of each balance. the problem I got, is that the program will only plot after the measurement runds, this could take a longer time. Now i found out, that multi threading can avoid this problem. but I don't know how to implement it in my existing code. May be some one can tell me how to add the classes on the right was. So I would be able to plot some other values while the main loop writes them in to the excel file.

The following is my basic code, sorry for the long code, but I can't show a smaller version without loosing the whole context. I cut out the measurement command for balance 2 to 10, and also I left only one plot command. Cause they all are working and very similar to the others.

The measurement function "def Measurement():" will take the longest time, and is in the moment the part which is running actively in the foreground

The measurement Function "def Measurement():" will take the longest time, and is in the moment the part which is running actively in the foreground. this will block all other commands in the GUI, and this leads to the queuing of this other commands. For example: I press the "plot" or "Help" button, and they will open after one run of the measurement loop.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Created on Thu Aug  8 15:22:25 2019

The following program, is planed and designed to collect the weight information form 10 OHAUS SCOUT SKX2202 balances.

The program generates an GUI for the user to input all needed information and dates for the measurements. 

After collecting, the program writes all needed and important information to an Excel file (`.xlsx`). Also the program should give the possibility to plot some weight values while the measurement is running. 

# import  all needed basic libraries
import time 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import os.path
import string 
import serial
import sys
import xlsxwriter

from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import datetime
from os import path

#import all needed libraries for the graphic user interface

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout,QRadioButton, QPlainTextEdit

#creating the main window, show the code to be an application 

app = QApplication([])

app.setStyle('Fusio')
app.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {margin: 10ex;}")
window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('Balance Messurements')

#creating the basic window elements 

#all buttons for the main window (text added to the button will show their use)
buttonOkName = QPushButton('Confirm User Name')
buttonOkAnzahl = QPushButton('Confirm input ')
buttonOkZeit = QPushButton('Confirm time ')
buttonStarter = QPushButton("Start")
buttonhelp = QPushButton("Help")
buttonClose = QPushButton("close")
buttonOpenFile = QPushButton("Open File")
buttonPlot = QPushButton("Plot Graph")
chooseTime = QLabel("Choose if your Input Time are Minutes or Seconds")

minWahl = QRadioButton("Minutes")
sekWahl = QRadioButton("Seconds")

#user input mask for the user name, only accept Letters, no numbers, no space

user_name = QLineEdit()
user_name.setPlaceholderText("User Name")
user_name.setInputMask("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaa")

#user input mask for number of measurements, only accept numbers , no Letters, no spaces
user_anzahl = QLineEdit()
user_anzahl.setPlaceholderText("Number")
user_anzahl.setInputMask('99999')

#user input mask for timeinterval, only accept numbers , no Letters, no spaces
user_zeit = QLineEdit()
user_zeit.setPlaceholderText("Timeintervall")
user_zeit.setInputMask('9999999999999')

#user input for the project name (written to the Excel file)
user_project=QLineEdit() 

#the labels to name the single inputfields
user_name_label = QLabel("User Name:")
user_anzahl_label= QLabel("Number of measurements:")
user_zeit_label = QLabel("Break interval:")
Savepath =QLabel("Saving Path: ")
nameoffile = QLabel("Filename: ")
proname = QLabel("Project Name: ")

#progressbar, get values at the lower code
progcounter = QProgressBar()

#implememting the single parts to a full layout

firstlay = QHBoxLayout()
firstlay.addWidget(user_name_label)
firstlay.addWidget(user_name) 
firstlay.addWidget (buttonOkName)
firstlay.addWidget(buttonhelp)

secondlay = QHBoxLayout()
secondlay.addWidget(user_anzahl_label)
secondlay.addWidget(user_anzahl)
secondlay.addWidget(buttonOkAnzahl)

layer10 = QHBoxLayout()
warning = QLabel("A breakinterval under 12 seconds can lead to irregular measurements.")
layer10.addWidget(warning)
layer10.addWidget(chooseTime)

layer11 = QHBoxLayout()
layer11.addWidget(minWahl)
layer11.addWidget(sekWahl)
layer11.addWidget(buttonOkZeit)

thirdlay = QHBoxLayout()
thirdlay.addWidget(user_zeit_label)
thirdlay.addWidget(user_zeit)

layer4 = QHBoxLayout()
notes = QLabel("Remarks/notes")
text_notes = QLineEdit()
layer4.addWidget(notes)
layer4.addWidget(text_notes)

layer5 =QHBoxLayout()
progres = QLabel("Progres: ")
layer5.addWidget(progres)
layer5.addWidget(progcounter)
layer5.addWidget(buttonStarter)

layer6= QHBoxLayout()
layer6.addWidget(proname)
layer6.addWidget(user_project)

layer7 = QHBoxLayout()
layer7.addWidget(Savepath)

layer8 = QHBoxLayout()
layer8.addWidget(nameoffile)

layer9 = QHBoxLayout()
layer9.addWidget(buttonPlot)

layer12 = QVBoxLayout()
layer12.addWidget(buttonClose)

#implementierung aller elemente in das zu zeugende Fenster

mainLayout = QGridLayout()
mainLayout.addLayout(firstlay, 1, 1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(layer7,  2, 1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(secondlay, 3 ,1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(layer10, 5, 1, 1,1)
mainLayout.addLayout(layer11, 6, 1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(thirdlay, 4,1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(layer6, 7, 1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(layer8, 9, 1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(layer4, 8, 1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(layer5, 10, 1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(layer9, 11, 1, 1, 1)
mainLayout.addLayout(layer12,12,1,1,1)

#befehl das Fenster zu zeigen 

window.setLayout(mainLayout)
window.show()
# funktion um Eingabe auf "NUr Letter" zu überprüfen  
allowed_alpha = string.ascii_letters + string.whitespace

#following all functions will be defined

def on_minWahl_clicked():

    global zeit 
    zeit_vorab = int(user_zeit.text())
    zeit = zeit_vorab * 60
    global Pause 
    Pause_vorab = int(user_zeit.text())
    Pause = Pause_vorab * 60
    global Zeitangabe 
    Zeitangabe = " minutes"
    global intervall
    intervall = 'Time [min]'

def on_sekWahl_clicked():

    global zeit 
    zeit_vorab = int(user_zeit.text())
    zeit = zeit_vorab
    global Pause
    Pause = int(user_zeit.text())
    global Zeitangabe
    Zeitangabe = " seconds"
    global intervall
    intervall = 'Time [sec]'

#function to confirm the user name
def on_OkName_clicked(self):

     #convert the input to a global string for all other functions 
    name = str(user_name.text())
    user = str(name)

# function to confirm the number of measurements 
def on_OkAnzahl_clicked():
    while True:
        try: 
            #convert the input to a global integer for all other functions 
            global Anzahl 
            Anzahl = int(user_anzahl.text())
            break 
        except Exception as inst:
            print (type(inst) )    # the exception instance
            print (inst.args)      # arguments stored in .args
            print (inst)           # __str__ allows args to be printed directly
            x, y = inst.args
            print ('x =', x)
            print ('y =', y)

#function to confirm the time for the break interval
def on_OkZeit_clicked():
    while True:
        try: 
            break 
        except Exception as inst:
            print (type(inst) )    # the exception instance
            print (inst.args)      # arguments stored in .args
            print (inst)           # __str__ allows args to be printed directly
            x, y = inst.args
            print ('x =', x)
            print ('y =', y)

        intzeit = user_zeit.text()
        if intzeit < 12:
            alert = QMessageBox()
            alert.setText('Intervall needs to be 12 seconds or longer!')
            alert.exec_()

# start the main function/measurement function of this program by click on start button 
def on_start_clicked(): 
    while True: #function to run the measurements 
        try:
            Measurement() #start the measurements 
            break
        except IOError:  # return information if an error appears 
            alert = QMessageBox()
            alert.setText('Failed start the measurements!')
            alert.exec_()
            break        

# function to check the saving path

def check_path():

   dt = datetime.now()
   global save_path          
   global user
   user = user_name.text()
   global filename 
   filename =  filename = 'data_'+  dt.strftime("%Y%m%d_%I%M%S") + '.xlsx'     # generates the file name
   save_path = ('C:/Users/satzh/.spyder-py3/CPU Temp Measurements/' +user+'/')  #generates the full saving path


   a = os.path.exists(save_path)    # function to found out if path exist

   if a == True:     # path exist = use the existing path

       saveText = QLabel("Savepath: "+ save_path)   #show saving path in the main window
       layer7.addWidget(saveText)

       #shows the saving path in a message box
       alert = QMessageBox()   
       alert.setText("Userpath exist, Data will be saved into: %s"%save_path)
       alert.exec_()

   else:    #path does not excist, 

       os.makedirs(save_path) # creats a new folder for the user, as save path
       saveText = QLabel("Savepath: "+ save_path) # shows the new savepath in main window
       layer7.addWidget(saveText)
       #shows the saving path in a message box
       alert = QMessageBox()
       alert.setText("Path does not exist, file will be generated at:\n%s" %save_path)
       alert.exec_()
   name_end = QLabel(filename)
   layer8.addWidget(name_end)

   #check if their is a file withe the same name (not really probably, cause it's always named for the current time )
   while True:
    try:
        path.exists(save_path,filename)

        global wb     # open an new excel workbook/file 
        wb = Workbook()

        global sheet  # creates in the workbook a new  sheet
        sheet = wb.active
        sheet.title =  "Book1"
        wb.save(save_path+filename)   # saves the workbook/file at the given path

        #if the file exist, adding a 1 to the name and produce a new file 
        new_filename = 'filename'+'1'
        global workbook
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(save_path+ new_filename) 
        global worksheet
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

        break        #if an error appears, it is creating a provisionally file 
    except TypeError: 
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(save_path + filename)    
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

        break

    else:
        os.makedirs(save_path)
        saveText = QLabel("Savepath: "+ save_path)
        layer7.addWidget(saveText)
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(save_path+filename) 
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# measurement main function, collect values form the balances and write this in an Excel file 
def Measurement():

    c = 0
    row = 2
    col = 0
    n = 0
    # generates the title line and basic information for the Excel file

    worksheet.write(0,0, 'Project Name:')
    worksheet.write(0,1, user_project.text())
    worksheet.write(0,2, "Remarks/Notes:")
    worksheet.write(0,3, text_notes.text())
    worksheet.write(0,4,"Number of measurements: %d"%Anzahl)
    worksheet.write(0,5, "Breakinterval: %d"%Pause)
    worksheet.write(1,0, 'Date' )
    worksheet.write(1,1, 'Balance 1')
    worksheet.write(1,2, 'Balance 2')
    worksheet.write(1,3, 'Balance 3')
    worksheet.write(1,4, 'Balance 4')
    worksheet.write(1,5, 'Balance 5')
    worksheet.write(1,6, 'Balance 6')
    worksheet.write(1,7, 'Balance 7')
    worksheet.write(1,8, 'Balance 8')
    worksheet.write(1,9, 'Balance 9')
    worksheet.write(1,10, 'Balance 10')
    worksheet.set_column('A:B', 30)
    worksheet.set_column('B:L',15)

    #generates and show a message box that the measurements are started
    alert = QMessageBox()
    alert.setText("Measurements in progress")
    alert.exec_()

    # generating the value list for each balance for the print command
    global lb1,lb2,lb3,lb4,lb5,lb6,lb7,lb8,lb9,lb10
    lb1 =[]
    lb2=[]
    lb3=[]
    lb4=[]
    lb5=[]
    lb6=[]
    lb7=[]
    lb8=[]
    lb9=[]
    lb10=[]

    # measurments loop, 
    while c <= Anzahl:
        dt = datetime.now()   #create a shortcut for the date and time value
        date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'd.mm.yyyy  hh:mm:ss'}) #create the format which is written to the Excel file
        worksheet.write_datetime(row,col, dt, date_format) 

        # the following notes  are for all 10 measurements loops the same:

        #Measurement loop for balance 1
        while True:
            try:
                bal1 = serial.Serial('COM7' ,9600,    bytesize=8, stopbits=1, timeout =0.1) #opens the serial/com-port for balance 1 
                #and set the bal1 variable for the port name/class

                break  #ends the loop when balance was opened
            except OSError:  #except Error for failing to open the serial port 
                alert = QMessageBox()     #generates a messagebox to say that an error appears
                alert.setText("Failed to open Balance 1")
                alert.exec_()
                break
        while True:
            try: 
                bal1.write(b'Z\r\n')             #sends the first few characters to the balance, to activate her and make her responding to the Computer 
                s=bal1.read(17)                  #reads out the  weight information
                bal1.write(b'\x50')              #sends the "print" command to the balance
                t=list(str(s))                   # creating a list of strings of the measurement values
                liste = t 
                satz = "".join(liste [3:13] )     # reads the numbers out of the list and generate a new combined string 

                zwischen_string = satz           # generates the values for the plotting lists 
                lb1.append(zwischen_string)      # connect the value to the print list
                gewicht = zwischen_string.replace('.', ',') #change the dot to a comma for the exported Value to excel
                worksheet.write(row, 1 , gewicht)           # writes the value to the Excel file
                bal1.close()                                # close the serial port
                break 
            except OSError:
                alert = QMessageBox()
                alert.setText("Failed to open collect and write the information form balance 1")
                alert.exec_()
                break

        row += 1 #say the program, to use a new row for the next measuremnt in the Excel file
        c +=1    # counter for measurements +1, next measurements for the while loop
        time.sleep(Pause) # set the break, which is given by the user 

        #loop to set the maximum number of list elements to 10
        #for the direct printing of the values

        def  check_plotlists():
            if len(lb1)>=10:
                del lb1[0]
            if len(lb2)>=10:
               del lb2[0]
            if len(lb3)>=10:
                del lb3[0]
            if len(lb4)>=10:
                del lb4[0]
            if len(lb5)>=10:
                del lb5[0]
            if len(lb6)>=10:
                del lb6[0]
            if len(lb7)>=10:
                del lb7[0]
            if len(lb8)>=10:
                del lb8[0]
            if len(lb9)>=10:
                del lb9[0]
            if len(lb10)>=10:
                del lb10[0]

        app.processEvents()   #allows to send back the percent value vor the processbar
        prozent =(n/Anzahl)*100 #creating the percent value
        progcounter.setValue(prozent) # gives back the percent value to the processbar
        n +=1                         #counter to generate the percent value
    workbook.close()   # close the excel file
    layer9.addWidget(buttonOpenFile) # add the "open file" button 

# öffnet am ende die angelegt datei

def on_OpenFile_clicked():

   os.chdir
   os.system('start excel.exe "%s%s"' % (save_path,filename ))

#helpFuntion, reads text from Help Instructions.txt file

#generating the help window, by clicking on the Help button 
def open_help():
    f = open('C:\\Users\\satzh\\.spyder-py3\\Help Instructions.txt',"r") #source for the help text 
    x = f.read() #reads the text from the txt. file 

    global windowhelp
    windowhelp = QWidget()
    windowhelp.setWindowTitle('Help') 
    buttonClose = QPushButton("Close")
    buttonClose.clicked.connect(on_close_clicked)
    helplayer1 = QVBoxLayout()
    help_text= QPlainTextEdit()
    help_text.appendPlainText(x)
    help_text.zoomIn(4)
    helplayer1.addWidget(help_text)
    helplayer1.addWidget(buttonClose)
    HelpLayout = QGridLayout()
    HelpLayout.addLayout(helplayer1,1,1,1,1)
    windowhelp.setLayout(HelpLayout)
    windowhelp.setGeometry(300,300 ,800,480 )
    windowhelp.show()

# close function for help window
def on_close_clicked():
    windowhelp.close()

#generating plot menu
def on_plot_clicked():
    #window generating

    global printwindow
    printwindow = QWidget()
    printwindow.setWindowTitle('Plott') 

    #button generating 
    Balance1=QPushButton("Print Balance 1")
    Balance2=QPushButton("Print Balance 2")
    Balance3=QPushButton("Print Balance 3")
    Balance4=QPushButton("Print Balance 4")
    Balance5=QPushButton("Print Balance 5")
    Balance6=QPushButton("Print Balance 6")
    Balance7=QPushButton("Print Balance 7")
    Balance8=QPushButton("Print Balance 8")
    Balance9=QPushButton("Print Balance 9")
    Balance10=QPushButton("Print Balance 10")
    Balance11=QPushButton("Print All together")
    Pclose = QPushButton("Close")

    #generate all buttons for the print menu
    printLayout1 = QHBoxLayout()
    printLayout1.addWidget(Balance1)
    printLayout1.addWidget(Balance2)
    printLayout1.addWidget(Balance3)
    printLayout2 = QHBoxLayout()
    printLayout2.addWidget(Balance4)
    printLayout2.addWidget(Balance5)
    printLayout2.addWidget(Balance6)
    printLayout3 = QHBoxLayout()
    printLayout3.addWidget(Balance7)
    printLayout3.addWidget(Balance8)
    printLayout3.addWidget(Balance9)
    printLayout4 = QHBoxLayout()
    printLayout4.addWidget(Balance10)    
    printLayout4.addWidget(Balance11)

    printLayout5 = QHBoxLayout()
    printLayout5.addWidget(Pclose)

    #generate the printlayout
    printFinal = QVBoxLayout()
    printFinal.addLayout(printLayout1)
    printFinal.addLayout(printLayout2)
    printFinal.addLayout(printLayout3)
    printFinal.addLayout(printLayout4)
    printFinal.addLayout(printLayout5)

    #connect the print buttons to print orders
    printwindow.setLayout(printFinal)
    printwindow.show()
    Balance1.clicked.connect(print_1)
    Balance2.clicked.connect(print_2)
    Balance3.clicked.connect(print_3)
    Balance1.clicked.connect(print_4)
    Balance5.clicked.connect(print_5)
    Balance6.clicked.connect(print_6)
    Balance7.clicked.connect(print_7)
    Balance8.clicked.connect(print_8)
    Balance9.clicked.connect(print_9)
    Balance10.clicked.connect(print_10)
    Balance11.clicked.connect(print_11)
    Pclose.clicked.connect(on_pclose_clicked)

#closing the print menue    
def on_pclose_clicked():
    printwindow.close()

#printing for balancce 1
    #following notes are for all print funtions the same 
def print_1():
    fig = plt.figure()  #generates the basic figure for the plot, like the new window
    plt.plot(lb1)       #give the dates which should be printed
    plt.title('Hydrogen Evolution')  #generates the head-title 
    plt.ylabel('Weight [g]')         # name fo the y cooridnates 
    plt.xlabel(intervall)            # name for the x intervall (is defined by the choose between seconds and minutes functions above)
    ax = plt.subplot(111)          
    ax.legend()
    plt.ylim(-1, 425)                # defined the intervall on the y coordinates 
    xmax= Anzahl*Pause               #defined the intervall on the x coordinates
    plt.xlim(0, xmax )
    plt.show()
    timestamp = time.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")                              #generates part of the saving name
    command = "fig.savefig('"+timestamp+"_h2evo_multiplot.png', dpi=200)"   # saves the figure
    exec(command)
    fig.savefig('multiplot.png' , dpi=200)





#closing the Mainwindow and main Process
def close_all():

    window.close()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    exit()

#connect the Buttons with their functions 

buttonOkName.clicked.connect(on_OkName_clicked) #confirm name with checking user name 
buttonOkName.clicked.connect( check_path) #confrim name with function to check saving path 
buttonOkAnzahl.clicked.connect(on_OkAnzahl_clicked) #confirm number of messurements
buttonOkZeit.clicked.connect(on_OkZeit_clicked)    #confirm time input
buttonStarter.clicked.connect(on_start_clicked)
buttonOpenFile.clicked.connect(on_OpenFile_clicked)
minWahl.toggled.connect(on_minWahl_clicked)
sekWahl.toggled.connect(on_sekWahl_clicked)
buttonhelp.clicked.connect(open_help)
buttonPlot.clicked.connect(on_plot_clicked)
buttonClose.clicked.connect(close_all)

app.exec_()
```

In an other thread here I found the following: QThread can run an event loop, QRunnable doesn't have one so don't use it for tasks designed to have an event loop.  From: [C++/Qt - QThread vs QRunnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791824/c-qt-qthread-vs-qrunnable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you want to run a function named my_func using a thread.

```
import threading
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_func, args=())
my_thread.start()
```

if you want the thread to exit after the whole program exits, type this before starting

```
my_thread.setDaemon(True)
```

if you want to pass variables that your function need (arguments). suppose you have a function add(num1, num2) that returns num1+num2, you pass num1 and num2 in the args in a list as follow:

```
add_thread = threading.Thread(target=add, args=([4, 6]))
```

Comment: I planed to work with "QMainWindow"  and  " QRunnable" like discirbed in here: https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/

But I will try it this way too

Comment: its mentioned there that pure python threading is ok,

Comment: how would you impliment this to the given code? 
I tried to call the messurment function "def Messurement()" this way. 
And the "on_plot_clicked" function. But the problem that the commands get queued  still remains.

Answer (score 0):

library such as [Quamash](https://github.com/harvimt/quamash) should be used to prevent Qt UI threading interrupts processes related thread execution.
Custom QEventLoop implementation could be alternative and time consuming way of doing similar thing.
If python threads and Qt UI threads not managed, code starts generating unexpected errors/behaviors

```
import sys
import asyncio
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QProgressBar
from quamash import QEventLoop, QThreadExecutor

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
loop = QEventLoop(app)
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)  # NEW must set the event loop

progress = QProgressBar()
progress.setRange(0, 99)
progress.show()

async def master():
    await first_50()
    with QThreadExecutor(1) as exec:
        await loop.run_in_executor(exec, last_50)
    # TODO announce completion?

async def first_50():
    for i in range(50):
        progress.setValue(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)

def last_50():
    for i in range(50,100):
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(progress.setValue, i)
        time.sleep(.1)

with loop: ## context manager calls .close() when loop completes, and releases all resources
    loop.run_until_complete(master())
```